# How can I scale the marked faces similar to inset?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, scale

I've got these faces extruded "into" the mesh:

[image]

and I would like to scale these faces equaly much from the boundry of all the faces. I mean from the not selected edges that you can see. So the selected arrow just gets smaller. Not like this:

[image]

which is when I scale it only on y and z axis. It feels like it should be possible. Since inset does this (but also insets the faces which I don't want)

[image]
this is what I get with inset. The "boundry loops" of the selected faces are "pushed" in equaly much. Thats how I would like to scale down those faces without inseting anything. But I can't figure out what pivot point or orientation to use.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused after reading your post. Can you post an example of what your desired end result is? Maybe upload the blend file as well so others can test and contribute.

Comment: I think you may want to scale along the normals, with Alt + s. It can shrink a shape more uniformly than the standard scale operation.

Comment: @Cultmethod I tried to specify a bit

Comment: @R-800 Alt+s just moved the faces along the x axis in the images

Comment: Mine was just a random guess because like Cultmethod, I'm confused after reading your post. So I'm not going to be able to recommend anything else, unfortunately.